# How to fix diacritics in PDF forms in Evince?

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, i18n, evince

I happen to live in Czech Republic and we have such letters like `ě`, `š`, `č`, `ť`, etc in the alphabet and use them everywhere, including addresses. Today I was filling a PDF form in Evince and noticed that some of these letters either disappear or make the following letter disappear in view/print mode (everything is ok when I am editing the field). Any ideas why can this happen and how to fix this?

XUbuntu 12.04, Evince 3.4.0.

Update: I have installed the Adobe brand Acrobat Reader (9.5.1) and it has no problems with the letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is caused by a known bug in [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (reported at least [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=36111) and [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17913)) related to unicode characters. There is no fix at the moment, you just have to follow the bug tracker.

Answer (score -2):

you need to install msttcorefonts

Comment: This might solve the problem, but is a bit minimal. Did this solve the issue for you or are you just 'guessing' this might solve the problem?